# Subhomogeneity of modulus of continuity in metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

If $(X, d)$ is a metric space, and $\delta > 0$, we define the **modulus of continuity** of $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $\omega_{f}(\delta)=\sup\{|f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})|\space |\space  x_{1}, x_{2} \in X, d(x_{1}, x_{2})< \delta \}$.

I'm supposed to prove that for every $c>0$, $\omega_{f}(c\delta) \leq c\omega_{f}(\delta)$.

This seems either easy, or just plain wrong, but I can't seem to prove it. One "counterexample" I've thought of (I'm not sure if it's correct) is a pretty trivial function $f:\{1, 2, 4\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(1)=10, f(2)=5, f(4)=-3, $ and here we have  $5=\omega_{f}(3\delta) > 3\omega_{f}(\delta)=0$ when $\delta \in (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]$.

Can anyone maybe put me on the right path?

Comment: Did you add in all the assumptions? What is the context of the requirement of this proof?

Comment: It's part 3 of an exercise under the chapter 'Metric Spaces' of my Analysis 2 textbook (Serbian).  Part 1 is to prove that the function $\omega_{f}$ is increasing, part two is to prove that $\omega_{f}$ is subadditive, and part 4 is to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous iff  $\lim_{\delta\to 0_{+}} \omega_{f}(\delta)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most definitely false.  Here's another counterexample.

Let $X = (-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the absolute value as metric.  Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ via 
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x \le 0 \\
1 & \text{if }x \ge 1.
\end{cases}
$$
It's trivial to show that this is uniformly continuous, and we can compute
$$
\omega_f(\delta) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } 0 < \delta \le 1 \\
1 & \text{if } \delta >1.
\end{cases}
$$

Now for any $0 < \delta <1$ and $c >1/\delta $  we have that $\omega_f(c\delta) = 1$ but $c\omega_f(\delta) =0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So that means I didn't go crazy. I will definitely be sending an e-mail to my professor (who also happens to be the author of the book I got this exercise from).

Comment: Sure.  One point that might be useful to you: the things you mention above in your comment (under your post) ARE true if you know much more about the metric space.  For instance, if $X$ is a convex set of a normed vector space, then all the things you mention above should be true.